# Cloud simulation software

Tags: simulation

I have ever browsed a website focusing on cloud (cloud in the sky, not cloud computing) simulation.

That's a company devoted to developing cloud simulation software and offer cloud simultation solution.

Anyone knows this website or the company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of companies doing middleware cloud simulation and rendering. It might have been [SilverLining](http://sundog-soft.com/features/real-time-3d-clouds/) by Sundog, or [trueSKY](https://simul.co/truesky/) by Simul.